# Using color with braces employing the TikZ calligraphy library

Tags: tikz-pgf

Three cheers to Andrew Stacey for giving us the `calligraphy` TikZ library that allows for elegant calligraphic braces in TikZ (something I've wanted for ages but was afraid to ask) -- among **many** other things. Output looks like this:

[image: Brace produced by TikZ calligraphy library]

which is produced with this code:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}

\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing,calligraphy}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[red,decorate,decoration={calligraphic brace,amplitude=6pt},thick] (0,0) -- (0,3);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Notice the `red` option to `\draw`, which seems to have no effect on the brace. I've tried all sorts of things (even `pen colour=red` which gives an error), but I can't seem to colorize the brace. Tried with both XeLaTeX and pdfLaTeX. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`pen colour` works for me:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=10pt,multi]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing,calligraphy}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw[pen colour={red}, decorate, decoration={calligraphic brace, amplitude=6pt}, thick] (0,0) -- (0,3);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: red fancy curly bracket]

Comment: As it happens, the presence or absence of braces is **not** the issue. My error was in assuming that `pen colour=red` belonged in the `\decoration={...}` statement. It does not. Again, my bad.

Comment: Yes, it is a little counter-intuitive. But it kind of makes sense because, if it was a regular `brace` decoration, your `red` outside `decoration={}` *would* change the colour. But actually, I just looked at the library's documentation :-).

Comment: As did I. What indicated the behavior that makes this work? Just curious to know what I missed...

Comment: @sgmoye I don't know if I have a good answer. `pen colour` seemed OK from the manual. It didn't like it inside `decoration` so the only other obvious place to try was really outside `decoration`. And I also did an example with a regular `brace` decoration, trying the colour inside and outside to see what gave an error and what worked, and then figured by analogy. The best thing I can really say is that I looked at the documentation and then ... er ... fiddled a little bit :-).

Comment: No problem. I fiddle a lot myself -- apparently just not enough.

Comment: I don't actually know why I ended with braces either ... So I'm glad you didn't ask me that ;).

Comment: If you've any suggestions for improvements to the documentation, please suggest them.

Comment: @LoopSpace It wasn't intended as a criticism. I always have to fiddle in order to figure stuff out, however good the documentation. It might be helpful to change one of the `calligraphic brace` examples to a different colour, though, as this is a common thing to want to do. The issue isn't really specific to your library but more a general TikZ thing, but it would probably be handy.

Comment: @cfr I didn't take it as a criticism.  Just looking for ways to make the package more accessible.  I'll put a coloured example in next update.

Comment: @LoopSpace Sounds good. I just wanted to be clear it wasn't intended that way. I think the additional example would be good. Greatly approve your spelling preferences - my TikZ options aren't all underlined in red by my editor for once!