# TikZ library 'calligraphy' and 'paths.ortho' doesn't work together

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikzlibrary

From question and answer in [Using color with braces employing the TikZ calligraphy library](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/315693/using-color-with-braces-employing-the-tikz-calligraphy-library)
I learned about library `calligraphy`. From test about it use I observe two things:

- the library 'calligraphy' had to be loaded after library `decorations.pathreplacing,`
- if you use  it together with library `paths.ortho` some of options in drawing of lines lost its function (without warning or errors, just don't appear):

An example:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=10pt,multi]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,decorations.pathreplacing,calligraphy}
\usetikzlibrary{paths.ortho}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[<->]  (0,1.5) -- + (3,0);
\draw[|->]  (0,1.0) -- + (3,0);
\draw[|-|]  (0,0.5) -- + (3,0);
\draw[{Bar[]}-{Bar[]}]  (0,0) -- + (3,0);
    %

\draw[decorate,
      decoration={calligraphic brace, mirror,
      pre =moveto, pre  length=1pt,
      post=moveto, post length=1pt,
      raise=3pt, amplitude=6pt},
      thick, pen colour={red}]  (0,0) -- (3,0);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

As you can see, bar ends on third line are not presented. How to resolve this (minor) problem?

Comment: Where is `paths.ortho` to be found?

Comment: package  wrote Qrrbrbirlbel, avaliable is https://github.com/Qrrbrbirlbel/pgf/blob/master/tikzlibrarypaths.ortho.code.tex and  https://github.com/Qrrbrbirlbel/pgf/blob/master/tikzlibrarypaths.ortho.tex. Information about it I find in his answer on question http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/45347/vertical-and-horizontal-lines-in-pgf-tikz

Comment: They are probably using the same letters to branch off in `@nextchar`. Also if I  remember correctly, `calligraphy` is old.

Comment: @percusse The calligraphy standalone package is old, but the calligraphy tikz library (which is part of the spath3 package) is most definitely not.

Comment: @LoopSpace Thanks. Then, I don't remember correctly  :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Firstly, this is nothing to do with the `calligraphy` package.  I get the same behaviour from the following MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
%\url{http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/315739/86}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{paths.ortho}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[<->]  (0,1.5) -- + (3,0);
\draw[|->]  (0,1.0) -- + (3,0);
\draw[|-|]  (0,0.5) -- + (3,0);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Missing bars]

I don't know *why* it is happening, because I don't know anything about the `paths.ortho` package.  But I can fix it with some judicious braces:

```
\documentclass{article}
%\url{http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/315739/86}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{paths.ortho}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[<->]  (0,1.5) -- + (3,0);
\draw[|->]  (0,1.0) -- + (3,0);
\draw[{|}-{|}]  (0,0.5) -- + (3,0);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

So I can only assume that the option `|-|` means something special for the `paths.ortho` package and it is picking up on that first before the arrow syntax gets a look at it.  Knowing how arrows are interpreted (i.e. quite late in the key parsing), this is not all that surprising.

[image: Reappearing bars]

Comment: `|-|/.style={%
   /utils/exec=\pgfmathsetmacro\qrr@tikz@hvvh@ratio{#1},%
to path={|-| (\tikztotarget) \tikztonodes}},%`

Comment: I see! Package `paths.ortho` introduce syntax as `-|-` and `|-|` for paths between two points.  For example `\draw[red]    (2,1) |-| (1,0);`. Apparently this syntax influence on syntax of `\draw` options. Before testing of `calligraphic brace` it newer happen this case (because I normally use `arrows.meta` package). Thank you for this finding.

Comment: @cfr, can you explain your comment? Is it contain fix for `paths.ortho`?

Comment: @Zarko No. That's from the library. It is just the concrete evidence substantiating what Loop Space surmised.