# TikZ library "calligraphy" doesn't work anymore

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikzlibrary

after my recent upgrades of `miktex` (may, 5) the `tikz` library `calligraphy` doesn't work anymore. for example, testing of [cfr answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/315693/using-color-with-braces-employing-the-tikz-calligraphy-library):

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=10pt,multi]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing,calligraphy}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw[pen colour={red}, decorate, decoration={calligraphic brace, amplitude=6pt}, thick] (0,0) -- (0,3);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

which previously works, now gives error:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> \g__prg_map_int 

l.707 ...igraphy pen copperplate}{\l__cal_tmpa_tl}

?
```

forcing compilation gives correct result.

it seems that with this upgrade is introduced a bug. do anyone can help me with workaround?

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/429859/tl2018-mactex-and-tikz-calligraphy-library